# TabBar - Navigate Back to the Rootlevel

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, mvvmcross, back, tabbar

Setup looks like this:

```
LoginView MvxViewController
   MainView MvxTabBarViewController
      -Tab 1 
         - View1 (MvxViewController)
      -Tab 2 
         - View1 (MvxViewController)
      -Tab 3 
         - View1 (MvxViewController)
```

On View1 a I have a Tableview (List), will be filled always differently - depends on the tab.

Everything works fine so far. The problem I face now is, that when I'm in View1 and press the "Back" Button on the NavigationController I will get back to the "LoginView" instead the "MainView" (Rootview where the tabs are).

I found following command `this.NavigationController.PopToRootViewController(true);` but I didn't find the right place to use it. (If it's even the right way)

I used this project to get the idea behind https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/master/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch/Views/TabBarController.cs

Any help appreciated!

EDIT:

I solved the problem now, by removing following code (commented section removed):

```
public class MyPresenter : MvxModalSupportTouchViewPresenter, ITabBarPresenterHost
{
    public MyPresenter(UIApplicationDelegate applicationDelegate, UIWindow window)
        : base(applicationDelegate, window)
    {
    }

    protected override UINavigationController CreateNavigationController(UIViewController viewController)
    {
        var toReturn = base.CreateNavigationController(viewController);
        toReturn.NavigationBarHidden = false;
        return toReturn;
    }

    public ITabBarPresenter TabBarPresenter { get; set; }

    public override void Show(IMvxTouchView view)
    {
        //if (TabBarPresenter != null && view != TabBarPresenter)
        //{
        //    TabBarPresenter.ShowView(view);
        //    return;
        //}
        base.Show(view);
    }
}
```

I still don't understand the purpose of this code as it's making troubles. By removing it, everything works fine. (Code was from the example, to find here: https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross-Tutorials/blob/0f313e3be66b06c110f587b653b9b0c831fb7164/Sample%20-%20CirriousConference/Cirrious.Conference.UI.Touch/ConferencePresenter.cs)

Comment: Do you have a tab bar controller within a navigation controller? I.e. are you calling at any point something like `[navigationController pushViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];`?

Comment: yes I do, on the MainView

Comment: I have a feeling that's against the interface guidelines. Can't remember where/when I read about it, but I've always understood that to be very bad practice. A tab bar controller can present navigation controllers, but not the other way around. Imagine that you have your root navigation controller presenting a tab bar controller, which in turn presents a navigation controller in itself. Would you have multiple navigation bars? What would you do with the one presented? It's a mess.

Comment: @GuyKogus it is indeed :) But lucky as I am I will not have this kind of behaviour.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally you use a CustomPresenter for this type of logic - see N=25 in http://mvvmcross.wordpress.com for one example.

Your custom presenter can do things like:

- hiding the top-level navigation bar (like on https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-25-Tabbed/Tabbed.Touch/Setup.cs#L41) - this can be done at different levels
- delegating `Show` requests to navigation controllers sitting within the tab children: like on https://github.com/slodge/NPlus1DaysOfMvvmCross/blob/master/N-25-Tabbed/Tabbed.Touch/Setup.cs#L58
- directly manipulating the `UIViewController[]` array - e.g. something like

  ```
  public override void Show(IMvxTouchView view)
  {
      base.Show(view);

      if (view is MainView 
          && MasterNavigationController.ViewControllers.Length > 1)
      {
          MasterNavigationController.ViewControllers = new UIViewController[]
              {
                  MasterNavigationController.ViewControllers.Last()
              };
      }
  }
  ```

For more on custom presenters, see https://github.com/slodge/MvvmCross/wiki/Customising-using-App-and-Setup#custom-presenters and http://slodge.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/presenter-roundup.html

---

This article might be especially useful - http://deapsquatter.blogspot.co.uk/2013/06/custom-presenter-for-uitabbarcontroller.html

Comment: thanks for the answer, I already had an own Presenter. I was able to solve my problem by removing some code. Could you explain me the purpose of this code (found in the cirriouscore example)... Take a look at my edit